# in linux kernel - init_task is per cpu?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Is init_task thread is per cpu? or just one ?
If Im iterating from Init_task ill get to all of the threads in all of cpus ?

for example , using the following Macro which define at [sched.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.14#L2349) :

```
#define do_each_thread(g, t) \
    for (g = t = &init_task ; (g = t = next_task(g)) != &init_task ; ) do
```

will iterate over **all** threads ?

thanks !

Comment: Which `init_task` are you talking about?

Comment: @wallyk init_task is the task_struct for 
process 0/swapper/idle task.